# How to parse Date object from JSON request with Form in Java Play

Tags: java, json, date, playframework-2.2

I have the problem of getting errors parsing java.util.Date type with Form in Java PLay 2.2.1. The Model of my sample class is:

```
   @Entity
   public class SampleModel extends Model
  {      
  @Id
  Long id;

  @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Required(message="endHour must be specified.")
  @Formats.DateTime(pattern="yyyyMMddhhmmss")

  private Date date;

  public setId(Long id){

    this.id = id;
  }

  public Long getId(){

    return this.id;
  }

  public setDate(Date date){

    this.date = date;
  }

  public Date getDate(){

      return this.date;
  }
```

}

And the use of the Form in the controller is like:

```
public class ControllerSample extends Controller{

   public static Result create(){

       JsonNode request = request().body().asJson();

       Form<SampleModel> form = Form.form(SampleModel.class).bind(request);

       if(form.hasErrors())
       {
          //It always get Errors with dates
       }
       ....

       return ok();
   }
}
```

In the end, the JSON I posted is like this one:

```
{"date":"20140318120000"}
```

I cannot find the way the Form correctly parses the Date object. Could somebody guide me?

Comment: Have you tried "yyyyMMddHHmmss" with big letter H?

Comment: Yes, I have. It keeps getting errors. Thanks for the suggesting.

Comment: Can you try separating date parts like this in the @Formats.DateTime( and the JSON you send: "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss"

Comment: I've ended up creating my own json parser for the whole entity and inside that method I've done the Date parsing. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: what's the error? have you tried changing the `@Temporal` type to `Date`?

Answer (score 0):

You can register a [custom databinder](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaForms) that is going to be used when you bind the form and the request.
Just look at the example on the official documentation and you can safely substitute the `LocalTime` they are using with your `Date`.

Edit: Oh, and do not forget to register the databinder **before** the form<->request binding so that it has effect on the binding.